# How to store jQuery or javascript variable in json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Could I know that is there any chance to save the jquery variable in json file ? Thanks in advance.

I have:

`var image='/test/test.png';`

I'm getting this path with my file upload

`<input type="file" name="imageurl" value="imagefile"></input>`

so, I have to save it in json file

like:`[{"name":"imageurl","value":"/test/test.png'"}]`

Please find my code:

**html:**

```
<form id="testId">
    <input type="hidden" value="/test/test1.png" name="Image1">
    <input type="hidden" value="/test/test2.png"  name="Image2" >
   <input type="file" name="imageurl" value="imagefile"></input>
   <input type="hidden" value="imagefile"  name="imageurl"></input>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="testFile"></input>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var imagepath =$('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');//test.png
var image = '/test/'+imagepath;
```

**my json file:**

```
[{"name":"Image1","value":"/test/test1.png"},{"name":"Image2","value":"/test/test2.png"}]
```

**but my required json file is:**

```
[{"name":"Image1","value":"/test/test1.png"},{"name":"Image2","value":"/test/test2.png"},{"name":"imageurl","value":"/test/test3.png"}]
```

Please let me know any solution for it.

Comment: You mean you want to construct a JSON?

Comment: what is a `jquery variable` ?

Comment: What problem are you having? Creating the data structure you want? Converting it to JSON? Storing it in a file? Your question is currently really broad and deals with lots of issues without showing any effort.

Comment: You can't save anything in file purely with `javascript` or any js framework like `jQuery` - from Browser.

Comment: @AdityaParab — That's not entirely true (but it is complicated subject that doesn't really fit in a comment).

Comment: @AdityaParab check this : http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: @Quentin : Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your reply, as I'm storing some of my form input fields to json file already, but my requirement is to store my above jquery variable value(var image='/test/test.png') into my json file with key/values.

Comment: @Dhana — You appear to have repeated the question without addressing any of the issues raised in the comments. Don't do that. Edit the question to address the things that have been highlighted as missing, show us what you have so far.

Comment: @Quentin, I have edited and given my exercise in the question, please check it once and let me know for anything.

Comment: I have created at the same: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/fv9oaycw/ .

Comment: There's still some odd inconsistancies in your question.  your JQuery code seems to have little relation to how you are generating your JSON. All it does is replace a path in INPUT controls with a type of file (of which your sample code only has one).   You seem to be saying you are missing one contol data 'Image3' in your JSON output .. but in your sample HTML you don't have an Image3 input?

Comment: Hi, got the solution at: http://jsfiddle.net/ce5uaub3/2/, It may help anyone. Thanks you all !!

Answer (score -2):

Use the following

```
var value=JSON.stringify($(form).serializeArray());
```

The above statement will return key value pairs of the form fields.

You can write data to a json file using node js.

If file already exists the you can use

```
fs.appendFile('jsonsample.json', value, function (err) {

});
```

For writing new file you can use

```
fs.writeFile('jsonsample.json', value, function (err) {

});
```

To manipulate the json objects that are read from file and rewriting data you can read the following resource as a starter

https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/how-to-use-json-files-in-node-js

Comment: I have edited and given my exercise in the question, please check it once and let me know for anything.

Comment: @Dhana check resource to add new value to json string array and use statements given to add to the file. You need to use node js for this. It's just a statement like jqiery to include node js

Comment: I am new to node js, Could you please provide any solution. And I have created the above query at: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/fv9oaycw/

Comment: Hi, got the solution at: jsfiddle.net/ce5uaub3/2, It may help anyone. Thanks you all !!